# Invoke Lambda with caller credentials from API Gateway when using a Cognito User Pool Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I have created an API in AWS API Gateway, and an Authorizer that uses a Cognito User Pool.
I would like to invoke the Lambda Function using the Cognito User credentials, but in AWS Console, the check "Invoke with caller credentials" is disabled.

[image]
Is there any way to set this option, may be via cli?

Comment: What would that look like, do you want the lambda to somehow only have the permissions the user has or do you simply want to know the user information / their claims?

Comment: I would like the Lambda function to be executed with the user, to avoid assume its role in the code of the function.

Comment: That is now how lambda works. Lambda has its own role and uses those credentials.

Comment: And the reason it's greyed out is because you need to enable IAM auth in the Method Request section but as @luk2302 mentioned this is probably not what you expect.